# Updating Firebird BLOB field appending text

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

### Problem

Can't append text to a blob field, when this value is **NULL**, using simple concat (**||**).

Docs base: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-blob.html

### Test Env

[image]

**Assuming types:**

- fieldTarget ~ *BLOB*
- tablePk ~ *VARCHAR(5)*

Like this:

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldTarget = fieldTarget || :string
WHERE tablePk = :pkTarget;
```

After execute, no one error returns but the field still **null**

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using Firebird 2.1, is it a dialect 3 database? What is the full type of `fieldTarget`? What happens? Do you get an error? What language and driver are you using? Maybe the problem is that `:string` is typed as a blob as well, and your driver doesn't handle this properly?

Comment: Somehow I have repeatedly read over _"when this value is NULL"_... any operation on null yields null.

Answer (score 0):

All string operations (like ||-concatenation) are bound by maximum `VarChar` size limit (which is 32 KBytes, which is less than 8200 letters in UTF-8 encoded text).

However there seems to be `BLOB`-oriented functions. It also does not need escaping `NULL`-values with `COALESCE`.

> `LIST` returns a string consisting of the non-NULL argument values in the group, separated either by a comma or by a user-supplied separator.

See [`LIST()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-aggfuncs-general.html#fblangref40-aggfuncs-list).

Hence, using *derived tables*:

```
Select LIST(ALL X, '') From
 ( Select fieldTarget as x From tablename Where tablePk = :pkTarget
      UNION ALL
   Select Cast( :string AS VarChar(8191) ) From RDB$DATABASE ) 
As TMP
```

The typecasting is to assign data-type to the parameter-only expression.

P.S. the documentation also claims that

> The ordering of the list values is undefined.

P.P.S. Ready to run example, tested on FB 2.1.7

```sql
Select LIST(ALL X, '') From
 ( Select Cast( :str_pre AS VarChar(8191) ) as X From RDB$DATABASE
      UNION ALL
   Select /* DATA column */ RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE
          From /* DATA table */ RDB$TRIGGERS
          Where /* PK ID */ RDB$TRIGGER_NAME  = :pkTarget
      UNION ALL
   Select Cast( :str_post AS VarChar(8191) ) From RDB$DATABASE
)
```

Passing names like `RDB$TRIGGER_1` would give you a *system trigger* that has no source text, thus has a `NULL` value in the field. Easy to check that you need no `COALESCE`-screening here.

Comment: Since Firebird 2.1, concatenation (`||`) supports (text) blobs, there should be no need for magic. See https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-concat.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but with two limitations: NULL-values are not skipped but result in NULL result, and only small VARCHAR-sized BLOBs can use it (IOW it is not extansion of operators to BLOBs but implicit typecasting BLOB-into-VARCHAR). See http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes217.html  "(v.2.1) At various levels of evaluation, the engine now treats text BLOBs that are within the 32,765-byte string size limit as though they were VARCHARs. Operations that now allow text BLOBs to behave like strings are: Assignments, conversions and concatenations (|| operator)"

Comment: Well, that is explicitly stated in the summary / table of contents: "“Short” BLOBs Can Masquerade as Long VARCHARs" :-D // Oh, the 3rd limitations: only sub_type-text BLOBs are going this way, not default "binary" BLOBs. Which, perhaps, makes sense, minding charset problems

Comment: I haven't rechecked 2.1, but in more recent versions there is no such limit that I'm aware. Blob concatenation will work for text blobs of any length (and so does substring and others); I haven't checked binary blobs. The null-behavior you mention is standard, and would also apply to varchar concatenation.

Comment: This NULL behaviour is standard, of course, but is not what the topic-starter wanted, judging by both his question and use of COALESCE in his own now deleted answer. @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `CAST("your blob null field" as type of "MY BLOB DOMAIN OF SUBTYPE_1")` inside a COALESCE, it works for me *(Tested in firebird 2.1)*:

[Firebird CAST](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-casting.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-cast)

[Firebird COALESCE](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-conditional.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-coalesce)

In the case I tested I had a "null" blob field (let's call it "NOTES") with the next domain information: `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0 SEGMENT SIZE 80`

Doing a `COALESCE(NOTES, '')` returns me the next error:

> Datatypes are not comparable in expression COALESCE

The trick was to create a domain of the BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 (let's call it "TEXT") and make a CAST to this domain before concat or get it:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NOTES AS TYPE OF TEXT), '') FROM MY_TABLE
```

In your case, the next example should work properly:

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldTarget = COALESCE(CAST(:fieldTarget AS TYPE TEXT), '') || :string
WHERE tablePk = :pkTarget
```

Take in account to create in the database the domain **TEXT** as a blob sub_type 1 before.

*PS: The real trick would be to cast to the domain of the field that is going to be updated.*

Answer (score -1):

The primary problem you are having is that the original value is `NULL`. Operations like addition, concatenation, etc on a `NULL` value will yield `NULL`. For a deep-dive into the details of `NULL`, consider reading the [Firebird Null Guide](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nullguide/firebird-null-guide.html).

The solution is to use `COALESCE` to provide a default (eg empty string) when the column is null*.

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldTarget = COALESCE(fieldTarget, '') || :string
WHERE tablePk = :pkTarget;
```

---

<sup>*: you already had this in your now deleted answer, but it was a bit obscured by the casts to varchar which shouldn't be necessary</sup>

Comment: i already tryed this way but returns this error: `SQL Error [335544454] [HY000]: filter not found to convert type 1 to type 2 [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544454]`

Comment: @gbragamonte That would mean the field is not a text blob (aka sub_type 1), but a blob sub_type 2 (BLR) which should be used for Firebird internal purposes only (and you shouldn't even be able to define blobs of that type, but I'm not sure if that protection already existed in Firebird 2.1).

Comment: @gbragamonte You may want to fix the issue and recreating the blob as one of the right type, or if you think it already is a blob sub_type text (or sub_type 1), then it would be really helpful to have a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel at least in FB2.5 (but i believe in any FB2.x) one can cast BLR-BLOB into VARCHAR, which invokes Firebird's built-in "dis-assembler" to convert "compiled" byte-code into more or less readable mnemonics. It would be weird if BLR blobs can be converted to varchar but not to txt-blob. P.S. maybe it is not the field, but the parameter that somehow gets subtype 2?

Comment: @Arioch'The The error is about from type 1 to type 2 which would happen on store, not from type 2 to type 1. Also, the way the OP is executing (in DBeaver) will result in the value being incorporated as a literal before execution, so there is no parameter. I could only reproduce it in Firebird 2.1 by manually setting the sub type of the field to 2 (using a system table update as you can't create a type 2 blob using DDL in 2.1).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i meant, if we have a `sub_type_1 || sub_type_2` or `sub_type_2 || sub_type_1` expressions, then most probably one of the operands would had to be typecasted to another, but which would be the leading one and which would be subject to conversion i don't know.